# Trying to save an image field on a user using services, but for some reason it isn't saving in base64

Tags: 7, media, services

So my server (running Drupal 7) is getting this information:

```
[field_picture] => Array
    (
        [und] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIwAAACMCAYAAA..... (the rest of a huge base64 string)
                        [filename] => test.png
                        [filemime] => image/png
                        [target_uri] => test.png
                        [filepath] => public://
                        [mimeType] => image/png
                    )

            )

    )
```

This is to a user endpoint, and this is the only field that doesn't update.

The rest of what is sent to the server looks like this:

```
[field_description] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 
                            [format] => 
                            [safe_value] => 
                        )

                )

        )

[uid] => 22
[roles] => Array
    (
        [2] => authenticated user
    )
```

And my AJAX to put this up:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: SITE_URL + "/" + ENDPOINT + "/user/" + localStorage.uid,
        type: 'PUT',
        crossDomain: true,
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': token
        },
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(json),

...etc
```

The request doesn't fail (or at least it doesn't go to my error callback) - what is going on here and why isn't it saving?

Comment: Watchdog errors? File system permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make two requests, the first you will POST the base64 encoded string of the file which in turn will return to you the file id, at which point you can make the second call to save the user entity with the file id on the field in question. I have a blog post about this here: http://tylerfrankenstein.com/code/drupal-services-file-create-example-json-and-jquery

Here's the gist of it (assuming your endpoint path is `api`):

```
// Get the file id...
$.ajax({
  type: "post",
  data: {
    "file":{
      "file": my_base_64_encoded_image_string,
      "filename": "my_image.jpg",
      "filepath": "public://my_image.jpg",
    }
  },
  url: 'https://www.example.com/api/file.json',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(result) {

    // Now that we have the file id, save it on the user entity.
    var userAccount = {
      field_picture: { und: [ { fid: result.fid } ] }
    };

    $.ajax({
      url: "https://www.example.com/api/user/" + localStorage.uid,
      type: 'PUT',
      crossDomain: true,
      headers: {
          'X-CSRF-Token': token
      },
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: JSON.stringify(userAccount)
    });

  }
});
```

Comment: You're pretty much the expert on this, so I'll test this and almost certainly accept your answer, haha.

Comment: Also I'm assuming I need a new token with each request?

Comment: No, you use the same token. Just have your application request a token upon startup, and after login/logout, and set the token aside, then you can use it for all subsequent requests.

Comment: I am getting a 401 unauthorized CSRF validation failed but only from my mobile device. What could possibly be causing that? I've temporarily given permission to create files to everyone, including anonymous to test this and it still won't work. It is happening on file creation.

Comment: I'd recommend trying to fetch a new token right before making the POST call, just to see if that gets it to work. It sounds like the token being sent up has expired.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what it was. Any idea why that would happen on mobile but not on desktop?

Comment: Well it sounds like you are saving the token somewhere, and it is expiring at some point. I'd ask where you are saving it... then just make sure to fetch a new token upon app start up, during login/logout/registration... and maybe even fetch a new token when the app comes back awake, in case their phone went to sleep.